# How To Update multiple tables In MS Access with VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access, sql-update, adodb

Every month I have to UPDATE my MS Access db from approximately 30 excel files. They have all the same structure and format. firstly, I have to consolidate all the data from all excel sheets in one.

Then I run the code (below) to update my db. However I run the code for every tables because I don't know how to improved the code in order to update using the primary key.

So have 3 questions:
The most important for me is : **How can i make this vba code update all the tables in once based on the Primary Key?**

Is it possible to say to the vba code to look at specific range in the excel template which correspond to a specific column in the MS Access db? In order to avoir to consolidate all the excel sheets before updating the db.

An then if both question below can be solved: Is it possible to select the Folder where all these excel files are and the code will loop through all files?

```
Public Sub UpdatePriceList()
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sProduct As String, sVariety As String, cPrice As Variant
' connect to the Access database
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " & _
    "Data Source=C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\Database1.accdb;"
' open a recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open "PriceList", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable

Range("A2").Activate  ' row 1 contains column headings
Do While Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    sProduct = ActiveCell.Value
    sVariety = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    cPrice = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value

    rs.Filter = "product='" & sProduct & "' AND variety='" & sVariety & "'"
    If rs.EOF Then
        Debug.Print "No existing record - adding new..."
        rs.Filter = ""
        rs.AddNew
        rs("product").Value = sProduct
        rs("variety").Value = sVariety
    Else
        Debug.Print "Existing record found..."
    End If
    rs("price").Value = cPrice
    rs.Update
    Debug.Print "...record update complete."

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate  ' next cell down
Loop
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

thank you in advance!

Comment: check this for your last question: http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/filesystemobject-in-vba/

Comment: Thanks you! it's what i need if I succeed to manage how to solve my two previous questions. I'll keep in mind this link.